# Getting redundancy error while updating changes from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, concurrency

### Populating data

```
Private Sub SearchDB()
    Dim strfacility As String = CmbFacility.Text.Trim.ToString()
    Dim strstatus As String = CmbStatus.Text.Trim.ToString()
    Dim strtype As String = CmbPtType.Text.Trim.ToString()
    Dim fromdt = Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim todt = Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) = True Then
        If CoderType.Trim = "administrator" Then
            If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                If ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And     ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                End If
            Else
                If ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND-Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                If ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Discharge_Dt > '" & fromdt & "' AND Discharge_Dt < '" & todt & "'"
                End If
            Else
                If ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "' AND Patient_Type = '" & strtype & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = True And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = False And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Facility = '" & strfacility & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = False Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                ElseIf ChkBoxFacility.Checked = True And ChkBoxStatus.Checked = False And ChkBoxPtType.Checked = True Then
                    sql = "select * from Patient_Data where Coder = '" & CoderName & "' AND Coding_Status = '" & strstatus & "'"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        sql = "select * from Patient_Data where AC_No = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    End If
    connection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        ds.Clear()
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        totalcount = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Label8.Text = "Total Count = " & totalcount
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Saving changes from datagridview changes

```
Private Sub SaveDataGridView()
    Try
        Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection
        adapter.Update(ds)
        MsgBox("Changes Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: In the populating data section, you need to add a `Finally` clause with `connection?.Dispose()`. Every time you use a DB connection, you should create it, use it, and dispose of it as soon as you can. The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement is good for that.

Comment: A lot of code... at least `If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then` can be reduced to `If CheckBox2.Checked Then` since `Checked` is boolean already and there's no point in checking whether True = True

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, if you are repeating similar things over and over, you should see if you can reduce it into a function. Surely, you could build the query once for all conditions, and reduce the logic based on the checkboxes